# Inflating a 2D or 3D convex hull

Tags: 3d, collision-detection, convex-hull

With the final goal of finding intersection between objects, we need to inflate their convex hulls of a small amount to check intersection even on adjacent objects.

Does a practical approach to inflate convex hulls exists?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Compute the center, and shift all vertices with respect to it?

Comment: "*we need to inflate their convex hulls of a small amount to check intersection even on adjacent objects.*" You do?

Comment: @Nicol: Yes, when geometry is transformed in 3D space you lose accuracy and inflating is mandatory. You don't have to consider only the picture case...

Comment: @Bart: add an answer so I can mark this question solved. Your idea works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of, particularly for a convex hull, is to compute a center-point within the hull. Then displace all vertices on the hull by a fraction with respect to the center.

That should give you a somewhat inflated hull to test for intersections.